# Vue.js one-way binding forms

Tags: forms, binding, vue.js

I'm new with Vue.js and I'm trying to test some features of this framework.
Now I'm testing the input forms, and I would like to make a one-way binding, without using the `v-model` directive, but I can't find any example. Anyone could help me, please?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is example of one way and two way binding

```js
var V = new Vue({
  el:'#vue-instance',
  data:{
    name:'Niklesh'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.4/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue-instance">
<div>One Way binding with input box <input type="text" :value="name"></div>
<div>One Way binding as text {{name}}</div>

<div>Two way binding : <input type="text" v-model="name"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok thank you! Another question, how can I set the initial data from an asyncronous function and then get the value on submit in vue.js one-way binding?

Comment: @Nuovo001: You need to add just like in pure javascript as by `id` or `name` or any seelctor to to `formData` which you are going to post as `formData.name=$("#name").val()` before submit.

Comment: @Nuovo001: what is the situation to not use `v-model` ?

Comment: In the past I've used Angularjs for web applications, and two way binding forms has not very good performance. Now I'm going to develop a new application, probably with vue.js, that has a lot of forms. Do you think vue.js two way binding has good performance? @user2486

Comment: @Nuovo001 : one way binding is to display text, and two way is for user input, its good to use two way if you are taking user input.

Comment: Your last input with v-model directive is also one-way binding.

Comment: @WaldemarIce: Thanks for comment but you can check [this](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html), `You can use the v-model directive to create two-way data bindings on form input and textarea elements`

Comment: @user2486 ok, so I will use two way data binding, but in the last versions of Angular they have added the Reactive Forms in opposition to the two-way forms, for better performance, and I have understood that they are one-way . Probably I have misunderstood. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user2486 Try in console V.name = 'anything'. Is input v-model reflecting your model changes?

Comment: @user2486 Angular 1 has two-way binding, as I remember. Vue have one-way binding. You can only create something which looks like two-way binding, as in your argument. But as I said, it is just looks like...

Comment: @WaldemarIce : its one way, when you chane in first input will not affect in all the way, like in text value or in last inputtext value

Comment: @WaldemarIce: Its really good to discuss, but why vuejs doc says as its two way data binding : [check this if you not checked](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html)

Comment: @user2486 If you want simulate two-way binding, you can create input like this `<input type="text" v-model="name" :value="name">`. Now, if you change the name with V.name='anything', input will react. But, it is still simulation, not real two-way binding. But it is questionable how this simulation is more performant than React implementation. So, your answer have almost nothing to do with reality, nor the users question.

Comment: @user2486 Read carefully. They are not saying "Vue is two-way binding...", but the are saying "You can create two-way binding".

Comment: @WaldemarIce: yes we can create two way data-biding with `v-model`, that s I am saying

Comment: @user2486 No. In answer you are stating, that this: `<input type="text" v-model="name">` is example of two-way binding in Vue. It is not.

Comment: @WaldemarIce : What it should be to make `two way data-binding` according to doc ?

Comment: @WaldemarIce : many example I found [first](https://jsfiddle.net/coligo/5hq3rmb6/) and [second](https://codepen.io/israelss/pen/Eyqgxz)

Comment: In my opinion using `v-model` is two way binding, like angularjs using `ng-model`...is correct? It reflects the changes in the js script automatically, or not?

Comment: Yes using `v-model` is `two way data-binding` according to vue doc, but @WaldemarIce have still doubt on this.

Comment: @Nuovo001 Vue is one-way binding framework. You can use the v-model directive **to create two-way** data bindings on form input and textarea elements. It automatically picks the correct way to update the element based on the input type. Although a bit magical, **v-model is essentially syntax sugar for updating data on user input events**, plus special care for some edge cases.

Comment: @WaldemarIce : I am sorry but did I use/say anywhere that `Vue is two-way binding framework` ? I just given the example what In vue doc.

Comment: @user2486 Aha, I understood. No, you don't. Not directly. But your answer is sligtly confusing, at least. Improve it. Just a bit. And I remove my down-voting.

Comment: @WaldemarIce : If you found anything confusing , you are free to edit my answer