# Is there any library or package to show and real time edit in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

**I want to show my portion of code in vuejs template just like below.**

[image]

So, How can I add show some piece of code & also let the user realtime edit there & render the output above.

Comment: use `v-model` to bind two-way, [Here is example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47349107/5856964)

Answer (score 1):

**Run following snippet!** -- Type something in textbox it will change the title accordingly.

```js
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    title:"Hello!"
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div class="alert alert-success" id="app" role="alert">
  <h4 class="alert-heading">{{ title }}</h4>
  <p>Aww yeah, you successfully read this important alert message. This example text is going to run a bit longer so that you can see how spacing within an alert works with this kind of content.</p>
  <hr>
  <p class="mb-0">Whenever you need to, be sure to use margin utilities to keep things nice and tidy.</p>
  
  Change Title : <input type="text" v-model="title">
  
</div>
```

Comment: I think he wanted code snippet code not just data-binding

Comment: That's a good one. but I'm looking for a good solution that acts as an editor. For example https://falcon-react.technext.it/components/avatar. Here in the code snippets users can edit, remove & add some code that will be rendered automatically.

Comment: I don't think this is vue.js specific requirement or need. You are searching for tool like Codepen or JsFiddle which can reproduce output as you type something in editor.